# Converting negative number in string to float (Python)?

Tags: python, numbers, negative-number

Ok. I give up.

I have a DataFrame with a column ("Amount") of large numbers:

```
Amount
-1 000 000,00
 4 848 903,00
-2 949 234,00
13 038 023,00
 7 985 232,00
 ....
```

I want to convert these to numbers that I can calculate with.

Let's investigate:

```
>type(b["Amount"][0])
str
```

Ok, it's a string.

```
>float("-1 000 000,00".replace(' ', '').replace(',','.'))
-1000000.00
```

Ok, works great!

To make a lambda thingy (to process all elements in column), I need it in a function:

```
def make_float(num):
    num = num.replace(' ','').replace(',','.')
    return float(num)


>make_float(b["Amount"][0])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: −1 000 000.00
```

What?!

```
>b["Amount"][0].replace(' ','').replace(',','.')
Out[258]:
'\xe2\x88\x921\xc2\xa0000\xc2\xa0000.00'
```

Oh no!! Unicode hell! I give up.

**Does Python have an easy function/method that will convert my numbers (including negative) to something I can calculate with?**

Comment: I even tried a function that goes like this: def make_float(num):
    
    num = num.replace(',','.')
    num = num.replace(' ','')
    num = num.replace('\U00002013', '-')
    num = num.replace(u'\N{MINUS SIGN}', '-')
    num = num.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore')
    
    num = float(num)
    return num

Comment: What does `print(b["Amount"][0])` prints out? And in the `make_float` functions, can you add a `print(num)` after you set the `num` variable and see what it prints out?

Comment: The function you wrote is works fine. The problem is with  `b["Amount"][0]` I guess

Comment: I'm reading this file with pandas.read_csv. Changing the encoding might or might not help?

Comment: The value of `print(b["Amount"][0])` is `-1 000 000,00`.

Comment: While the value of `b["Amount"][0]` is `'\xe2\x88\x921\xc2\xa0000\xc2\xa0000,00'`

Answer (score 2):

looks like you have a problem with the minus('-') symbol in the string.

**Try:**

```
def make_float(num):
    num = num.replace(' ','').replace(',','.').replace("−", "-")
    return float(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue. The problem is to get the first value of the column as a value you should use `pd.Series.values[0]`.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['-1 000 000,00'])

def make_float(num):
    num = num.replace(' ','').replace(',','.')
    return float(num)

s.map(make_float)

# 0   -1000000.0
# dtype: float64

make_float(s.values[0])
# -1000000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you try to encode it?

```
def make_float(num):
    num = num.encode('latin-1').replace(' ','').replace(',','.')
    return float(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data contains unicode minus sign (one of several minus signs in unicode) and non breaking space (one of several space characters in unicode)

You can use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to convert characters to a format that can be correctly parsed by `float()`.

```
def make_float(num):
     return float(num.translate({0x2c: '.', 0xa0: None, 0x2212: '-'}))

make_float('−1\xa0000\xa0000,00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This seemed to do the trick.
It's a solution in 3 steps.

1. I checked my dataset with `chardetect data.csv`
   It said 'utf8' with a confidence 0.99
2. I made sure to pass that into my pandas.read_csv: `pandas.read_csv(data....., encoding = 'utf8')`
3. I made a function,

```py
def make_float(num):
    num = num.replace(u'\N{MINUS SIGN}', '-')  # encode the minus sign
    num = num.replace(',','.') #change the decimal separator from comma to dot
    num = num.replace(unichr(160), '') # encode the (non-breaking) space to ''
    num = float(num)
    return num

I then passed this function to the pandas.read_csv thing with `pandas.read_csv(data...., encoding='utf8', converters={'Amount':make_float}) `

Working good so far.
```